# Slow Postgresql Query on Small Table

Tags: postgresql

I have a total of seven rows in my table. A `SELECT * FROM myTable` takes more than five minutes. A `SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY id` takes 0,2 seconds. `id` is the primary key.

If I `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` the slow query, the result is the following:

```
Seq Scan on myTable  (cost=0.00..483960.16 rows=1053 width=2154) (actual time=218691.468..358475.782 rows=7 loops=1)
Planning Time: 0.089 ms
Execution Time: 358475.821 ms
```

Postgresql version is 11.8.

I am not a database expert - any hints where I can start with my search?

//Edit

`\x; select * from  pg_stat_user_tables where relname='myTable';` returns:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-------+-----------------------------------------------
relid               | 3781321
schemaname          | public
relname             | myTable
seq_scan            | 64538
seq_tup_read        | 443186
idx_scan            | 5861523
idx_tup_fetch       | 5863962
n_tup_ins           | 1
n_tup_upd           | 5861341
n_tup_del           | 0
n_tup_hot_upd       | 4692969
n_live_tup          | 6
n_dead_tup          | 515978
n_mod_since_analyze | 2466207
last_vacuum         | 
last_autovacuum     | 2020-06-06 19:13:08.16919+00
last_analyze        | 
last_autoanalyze    | 2020-06-06 19:13:08.520293+00
vacuum_count        | 0
autovacuum_count    | 379
analyze_count       | 0
autoanalyze_count   | 368
```

The Create Table Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE public.instagram_android_api_instagramloginandroidapi
(
    id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('myTable_id_seq'::regclass),
    u character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    p character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    e character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    ep character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    s smallint NOT NULL,
    i inet,
    z character varying(255) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    s text COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    dtlu timestamp with time zone,
    dtll timestamp with time zone,
    sct integer NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT myTable_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE public.myTable
    OWNER to xxxxxx;
```

Comment: Please post DDL of table and output (run with `psql`) for `\x; select * from  pg_stat_user_tables where relname='myTable';`

Comment: Hey @pifor. I added the result of the latter statement. With the "DDL" do you mean the CREATE statement of the table?

Comment: Yes for CREATE TABLE statement. Can you try to run `analyze mytable;` and re-run SQL statement ?

Comment: Does `vacuum full analyze mytable;` change anything?

Comment: I added the DDL. `analyze myTable;` had no effect. However, `vacuum full analyze myTable` did the trick. Thanks! Awesome! 

Now `n_dead_tup` and `n_mod_since_analyze` are close to 0. Can anyone explain to me what the problem is and how to mitigate it in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table had a lot of UPDATE statements and autovacuum did not run since 12 days.

The more the table has UPDATE/DELETE statements the more autovacuum should run.

See [autovaccum](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/routine-vacuuming.html#AUTOVACUUM).